bandstructure of CrI3 using QE
I want to plot bandstructure, PDOS and DOS of AFM monolayer CrI3 using QE. I computed sfc, nscf, bands. the problem i am facing is the plots. please i need help. bellow are the links to the output files obtained.

sfc (pw.sfc.out)
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SYISvv5hYOFzcQovFe06Le4ulPkNjHv2eDw_ySgXuxQ/edit?usp=sharing
nscf (pw.nsfc.out)
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LZBKeof5P1c7qDs_NSt8zKqL6nm5LC0tIeP-c7k3iG8/edit?usp=sharing
bands (bands.out)
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PsvrwRit1eJy8dLEt4YfNnVpqJYJFS515u9DuLMXS0U/edit?usp=sharing
bands.pp.out
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I0Ge7LuMGLF3odTLcl5HLlAptmVZ5nC3qFqscy3mIRs/edit?usp=sharing
i can provide any other thing neede like input files and so on.
thank you


Hello & welcome to MMSE! It seems you ran the calculations correctly for plotting the band structure. What problems are you facing about the plots exactly? You can obtain the band structure by either running the interactive plotband.x or using gnuplot/xmgrace/python (check the *.gnu files). To plot the DOS, you need to run the dos.x after running an nscf calculation with occupations = "tetrahedra".  For PDOS, you need to use projwfc.x. These will produce an energy vs dos data file which can be plotted using gnuplot/xmgrace/python, for example.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

+1 and welcome to our new community! Please see this and edit your post accordingly.

I did all this but the output of the plot (graph) is different from those in previous work, maybe there might be a problem in my input files. seroiusly  i need help. if someone can help in the work here my email Id (musaelbulatory@gmail.com)
